# Getting on the right track with Tic-Tac-Toe in JSP

Tags: jsp, tic-tac-toe

I have such a task in my college:
*Using JSP create a site that allows a client to play Tic Tac Toe. Every "move" shall be controlled by the server. Game status should be remembered in the session and every move shall be realised by calling the same .jsp page (with appropriate parameter), what will cause drawing it again with a properly updated board. (...) Whole task should be delivered in on JSP file, no war, ear or app files. Structures remembered in session may be standard JDK classes, e.g. HashSet.* 
I hope that I have translated it well enough as the task is written in my native language.

Anyway what I would like to ask you is what would be a good way to do it and what should I pay attention to? I am a noobie, never have used JSP before, and also have rather limited programming knowledge. What would be a good way to create the "board" (buttons? table?), to collect data from user (sending a form after clicking on buttons?), what methods could be useful? I have followed a basic tutorial on JSP and but still I'm not sure hot to approach this task.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well i'm not quite familiar with the jsp, but i've done tic-tac-toe in java for a console base and have done it in JavaFX. I cannot teach you or give pointers about jsp, but about tic-tac-toe - i used four separate classes. One for making a board, one for players, one for drawing the winning line and main class which will run it all.

WinLine is easy class - it is the class which has constructor and getters and setters inside.

```
    public WinLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    this.x1 = x1; //coordinate one on x
    this.y1 = y1; //coordinate one on y
    this.x2 = x2; //two on x
    this.y2 = y2; //two on y
}
```

and getters and setters for them, x-ses and y-s.

this is PLAYER Class:

```
public enum Player {
//Player who does X-ses
PLAYER_X,

//Player who does O-s
PLAYER_O;


public static Player getNextPlayer(Player player) {
    if (player == PLAYER_X) {
        return PLAYER_O;
    } else {
        return PLAYER_X;
    }
}
```

This is not the full answer, but i'll hope this helps you into right direction.